# Why the interface of std::copy_n in c++ is incorrect?

Tags: c++, c++11, interface, stl

While reading the book([Notes On Programming](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf)) and ongoing [video-lecture](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHxtyCq_WDLXFAEA-lYoRNQIezL_vaSX-) by Alexander Stepanov, I learnt some amazing fact about impact of good interfaces in the program.

He has explained about interface design is very important part and it has significant impact on the programs. He has mentioned the following points while designing the interfaces with the following STL algorithm/function "std::find_if".

```
template<class I, class P>
I  find_if (I first, I last, P pred) {
  while (first!=last) {
    if (pred(*first)) return first;
    ++first;
  } 
  return last;
}
```

In the above, he has explained that

1. do not return **"pred"** as it is passed by caller of this method.
2. do not return **"last"**  as it is  known and passed by caller of this
   method. Never return something which is known and passed by caller
   to this function.
3. **"first"** should be the return from this method as during the
   execution of the method, this might have changed so this is
   something which is new/update  for caller hence  should be passed.

So the main idea about which I learnt after analyzing the C++ STL interfaces are:

- Pass as much information as possible which gives caller the information regarding the work done by that particular function.
- Do not return the information which is already known and does not changed during the execution of function.

Based on the above point, he has mentioned that **std::copy_n** interface is incorrect and should be fixed in near future

FROM

```
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt >
OutputIt copy_n( InputIt first, Size count, OutputIt result );
```

TO

```
template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt >
pair<InputIt, OutputIt> copy_n( InputIt first, Size count, OutputIt result );
```

Could someone explain about why this would be nesseary and useful to caller of this function to get the information about *first* and *result*?.

Comment: Imagine you need to copy one list to another list, but swapping the parts [0, N/2) [N/2, N) (where N is the length of the list). You can implement this via two calls to `copy_n` (remember `list::size` is in O(1)), but you need the iterator pointing to N/2 for the second call. The new interface of `copy_n` can return that as the `.first` of the pair; if you don't have it, you need to manually increment the `begin()` iterator, which is in O(N/2).